# How to use addFieldToFilter() in field generated in sql?

Tags: filter, collection-filtering

If I try to filter a field in the existing table works, but a field generated by max () does not work, even renaming,  display the error getBackend().

Examples:

**observer**

```
$collection->getSelect()->columns(array('last_order' => 
            new Zend_Db_Expr ("(SELECT MAX(created_at) FROM " . 
            $collection->getTable('sales/order') . " WHERE customer_id = e.entity_id)")));
```

**grid - _prepareCollection()**

```
$this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('last_order', 1);
```

I was wondering how can I make this filter work with my select

Comment: Define 'does not work'.  Can you also expand on what it is you are trying to do?

Comment: I am creating new fields in the grid, however when the field is not native of  table, the filter of error getBackend() if max(), min(), sum() etc, even retitle

Comment: Any particular reason you are using `columns()`, a `join()` is the normal way to include data from other tables.

Comment: I researched several examples and what worked was with columns (), nothing in particular. @JonathanHussey

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an answer I gave ages ago on stackoverflow which deals with exactly that issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9531624/485589

The gist of it is that when you add a column with a computed value, you also need to supply the SQL filter syntax for it.
There are several ways that can be done, all outlined in the post linked to above.

Comment: Thank you, the difference is I'm using a date field, callback did not work, can you tell me how would getCondition () the range of dates?

Comment: Please update your post to include the code for the callback.